# Updating an html page according to an array with php

Tags: php, html, css, arrays

I'm building a webpage where data will be updated according to an external PHP array.
The words in those arrays should be printed as h1 tags inside 4 different div blocks which are under the "container" div.

My question is that how do I get those data from the PHP and print it in different classes in the HTML DOM without repeating PHP code for each and every div by calling out their class names separately..

php array:

```
<?php
$wrds=array("Home", "Buy", "Contact", "About");
?>
```

Html code:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="grid-item blue"></div>
      <div class="grid-item red"></div>
      <div class="grid-item orange"></div>
      <div class="grid-item green"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "without repeating php code in every div"?

Comment: You use a loop. Btw, your "php array" is not a php array.

Comment: When do you execute the php file? Are you getting the array with ajax or running the file before the HTML? If running it before HTML then you can just change the HTML doc to a php file and write some php in your HTML and change whatever you want according to your array, if doing it by ajax I would echo back a json from the HTML and update the HTML DOM with the returned json.

Comment: <?php $wrds = array('Home', 'Buy'); foreach($wrds as $item){ echo '<div>'.$item.'</div>'; } as @kerbholz mentioned

Comment: Thanks @kerbholz I missed 'array'. **Sorry**.

Comment: @Patrick Actually I'm trying to print tweets with twitter api. I still didnt got aproved from the dev.twitter . Therefore I created an array and moved on.

Comment: @Coli, By "repeating/" i meant using exact same internal php script in each of those divs and updating the content. In this case i'm using an external code.

Comment: @NavinThamindu I think it would be easier for us to help you if you output the result you want. Have you tried the twitter search api, when I used it (5 years ago) I can't recall you needed to auth yourself to get a list of tweets.

Comment: @Patrick I want to make a website which shows tweets in realtime according to hashtags. I'm just a newbie, i'm planing to extend these features. like using bootstrap and reactjs to create a beautiful ui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the colors into an array also, which results in the following code for the list:

```
<?php
$wrds=array("Home", "Buy", "Contact", "About");
$colors=array("blue", "red", "orange", "green");

echo '<div class="container">';

$length = count($wrds);
for($i=0; $i<$length; ++$i) {
    $color = $colors[$i];
    $wrd = $wrds[$i];
    echo "\t".'<div class="grid-item '.$color.'">'.$wrd.'</div>';
}

echo '</div>';
?>
```

The `for($i=0; $i<$length; ++$i)` is a for-loop. The `for` has three expressions as "arguments". The first expression sets `$i` to zero, the third expression increases `$i` by one in each repeat of the loop. The second expression is evaluated as a logical value. While the second expression is true, the loop is being repeated. The overall effect is to count from zero to one below the value of `$length` and to execute the loop body between the `{..}` for each value of `$i`.

Comment: Thanks @Adder, but can you explain me what is happening in 'for($i=0; $i<$length; ++$i)' please?

Comment: Explained the for loop